# How to get ongoing notifications of unread texts?

Tags: iphone, notifications, alert

One of my family members texts me at night when they are having nightmares. I want to know when they text me at 4 am instead of sleeping through it.

Is there a way to make text notifications keep going off until read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you’re going to get is to set Messages alerts to repeat 10 times by going into Settings → Notifications → Messages. There, swipe to the bottom to reveal the `Repeat Alerts` menu:

[image: Repeat Messages Alerts]

This will cause Messages notifications to ring for 20 minutes after the initial one, or until you’ve read/dismissed them.

Next, make sure `Do Not Disturb` is disabled by going into Settings → Do Not Disturb and toggling both `Manual` and `Scheduled` to `Off` (there are no VIP notifications in Messages yet).

You could also assign a custom loud and obnoxious text tone to the family member in question that will make it more likely a message from them will wake you up, but that alert sound will trigger for all text messages they send you, even during the daytime.

Coworkers who were on-call 24/7 also found it useful to turn on `LED Flash for Alerts` under the `HEARING` section of Settings → General → Accessibility.

If you lay your iPhone face down at night it will flash brightly when you receive a notification, although this will be active at all times for *all* notifications, so you might need to disable this every morning and re-enable it at night.

[image: LED Flash for Alerts]

A note on Do Not Disturb: if you have a habit of using Do Not Disturb and occasionally forget to turn it back off, you can make sure it gets disabled at night by *enabling* `Scheduled` for a 1-minute duration every evening, say, from 10:30 to 10:31 p.m., or sometime before you go to bed.